# Replacement for a custom CIFilter in iOS 12.

Tags: ios, swift, ios12, cifilter

Since iOS 12 CIColorKernel(source:"kernel string") is deprecated. Does anybody of you know what is Apples replacement for that?

I am searching for a custom CIFilter in Swift. Maybe there is a Open Source libary?

Comment: From iOS 12 CIColorKernel is updated with CIKernel and CIWarpKernel you can check the details in the documentation.
https://developer.apple.com/metal/CoreImageKernelLanguageReference11.pdf

Comment: Thanks, that was the right way. At my point this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cikernel helps me

Comment: Just a heads up if you're supporting iOS 12: the iPad Air 1 runs iOS 12 but cannot use MSL (metal shading language), as MSL apparently requires an A8 or newer CPU (iPad Air 1 has A7). Source: WWDC 2017 510 - https://asciiwwdc.com/2017/sessions/510

Answer (score 3):

It was announced back at WWDC 2017 that custom filters can also be written with Metal Shading Language -
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/writing_custom_kernels

So now apparently they are getting rid of Core Image Kernel Language altogether.

Here's a quick intro to writing a CIColorKernel with Metal -
https://medium.com/@shu223/core-image-filters-with-metal-71afd6377f4

Writing kernels with Metal is actually easier, the only gotcha is that you need to specify 2 compiler flags in the project (see the article above).

Comment: Thanks, I found also this tutorial. But I am stuck with: 

xcrun metal -fcikernel Filter.metal -o Filter.air
xcrun metallib -cikernel Filter.air -o Filter.metallib

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992783/metallib-error-reading-module-invalid-bitcode-signature

Comment: Stuck where exactly?

Comment: While I am trying to change the .air file to .metallib I just get: metallib: Error reading module: Invalid bitcode signature

Comment: Look here: https://medium.com/@shu223/core-image-filters-with-metal-71afd6377f4 and https://developer.apple.com/metal/MetalCIKLReference6.pdf Page 9
I followed this steps and the commands are the same like the build parameter. With CIKernel I need .metal for the kernel to build my own CIFilter.

Comment: I still do not understant the `.air` part. Obviously, its format is different from `.metallib`. If you have a filter written in Core Image Kernel Language, you will need to rewrite it in Metal Shading Language from scratch.

Comment: I wrote a .metal File with the kernel. This I compiled to an air file and the next step is to compile it to metallib to use it in project.
To create a CIKernel I need a metallib file. The named flags are doing the same, but first I want to test is through the terminal where I get the error.

Comment: I see. I never used CLI for that purpose, only Xcode project build settings. In project, it works alright. As for CLI, I commented your other question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992783/metallib-error-reading-module-invalid-bitcode-signature

Answer (score 2):

I attempted to follow along with these blog posts and the apple docs, but this integration between CoreImage and Metal is quite confusing. After much searching, I ended up creating an actual working [example iOS app](https://github.com/mdejong/CoreImageMetalFilter) that demonstrates how to write a Metal kernel grayscale function and have it process the CoreImage pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
 let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "metallib")!
 let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
 let kernel = try! CIKernel(functionName: "monochrome", fromMetalLibraryData: data)
 let sampler = CISampler(image: inputImage)
 let outputImage = kernel.apply(extent: image.extent, roiCallback: { _, rect in rect }, arguments: [sampler])
```

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cikernel/2880194-kernelwithfunctionname): 
"You need to set these flags to use MSL as the shader language for a CIKernel. You must specify some options in Xcode under the Build Settings tab of your project's target. The first option you need to specify is an -fcikernel flag in the Other Metal Compiler Flags option. The second is to add a user-defined setting with a key called MTLLINKER_FLAGS with a value of -cikernel:
[image]