# metallib: Error reading module: Invalid bitcode signature

Tags: ios, c, iphone, metal

I have following Filter.metal file

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
#include <CoreImage/CoreImage.h> // includes CIKernelMetalLib.h

extern "C" { namespace coreimage {

    float4 myColor(sample_t s) {

        return s.grba;
    }

}}
```

I am trying to compile it with:

```
xcrun metal -fcikernel Filter.metal -o Filter.air
xcrun metallib -cikernel Filter.air -o Filter.metallib
```

But I get this Error:

```
metallib: Error reading module: Invalid bitcode signature
```

I am trying to create a custom CIFIlter and I followed this: https://medium.com/@shu223/core-image-filters-with-metal-71afd6377f4 
tutorial.

The command lines I got from https://developer.apple.com/metal/MetalCIKLReference6.pdf.

How can I compile my file without this error?

Comment: I can reproduce this with the default toolchain in Xcode 10 and Xcode 10.1 beta 4. Seems like a bug. You should consider filing a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: I can reproduce it with Xcode 10 build 10A255.

Answer (score 6):

The response from Bug reporter was:

> Apple Developer Relations
> October 29 2018, 4:08 AM
>
> Engineering has the following feedback for you:
>
> The documentation is incorrect here.  One should add a “-c” to force an AIR file, i.e.,
>
> ```sh
> xcrun metal -fcikernel MyKernels.metal -c -o MyKernels.air
> ```
>
> We are now closing this bug report.
>
> If you have questions or comments about the resolution, please update your bug report with that information so we can respond.

Comment: Good that they know that their documentation is incorrect but aren't fixing it. Apple moment.